# WordPress Code Flow

Tags: wp-head

I was interested in checking out how the WordPress code flow works... When I googled it, ( probably with the wrong keywrods), all I ended up was this;

http://codex.wordpress.org/User:DavidHouse/Wordpress_Code_Flow

which is an excellent shot at it but very very old thus worth nothing today.

I also searched how the heck wp_head works, could not find it neither.

In order to understand wp from the ground up, I thoght I should get a full grasp of from url to all the way to wp_footer() what really happens... Ant pointers in this regard is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Probably the Program Flow on ToolPress is something for you: [Wordpress 3.0 Program Flow File Inclusions (Default Request)](http://toolpress.de/tools/Toolpress_-_Wordpress-3.0-Program-Flow-0.2-2010-06-28.pdf); PDF. Contains important filenames, constants and hooks. My Favorite Cheat Sheet so far for the code flow stuff.

Comment: that link is now dead :( I've put a link that references many different wp charts and is dated 10/2012 as an answer below. http://www.tomjn.com/168/wordpress-flow-charts-diagrams/

Answer (score 2):

Also you can see on the WP Stack, [here my version](http://wordpress-buch.bueltge.de/das-wordpress-buch/downloads/seite-242/) for download.

Comment: Also a nice idea to sketch the overview.